# How Can I Choose An Image From My Xamarin Resources?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an image but I want to use a image from my resources folder, I drag and drop that image into the resources folder, and I see that inside it have more folders, can someone explain me also for what is one of this subfolders?

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#native-resolutions-retina-and-high-dpi

Comment: Also there is a blog how to use resource folders for Android and iOS : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-images-icons-and-splash-screen-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android:

..\Resources\drawable

However there are multiple folders inside resources to handle different resolutions. If you want to provide different resolutions do so. Otherwise the resource in drawable will be used.

For iOS:

..\Resources\

Make sure to provide @2x to support retina display.

For UWP:

store images in root folder

Answer (score 0):

iOS, Android, and UWP include support for different image resolutions, where the operating system chooses the appropriate image at runtime based on the device's capabilities.

- For android :
  You need to put your images in `resources/drawable/`, every application should have alternative drawable resources for different screen densities. You should have images with the same filename in the different `drawable-xxx` folder.
  [This article](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) will help you.
- For UWP:
  You must place your images in `\Assets\Images`. You can provide variants of an image resource by creating folders for different scales :

> Assets\Images\scale-100\img.png
>
> Assets\Images\scale-200\img.png
>
> Assets\Images\scale-600\img.png

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast) will help you understand.

- For iOS :

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=vsmac) you have everything

Comment: I have a question regarding your UWP. When I am calling my resource in a crossplatform project all I have to do is to type the imagename.fileextension. No path. That is why I need my images in the root folder. Android and iOS manages this on itself. Don't you think it is is hard to always write the path?

Comment: @JoakimM I agree with you, I have the same problem with UWP applications. I always have to write the full path of images. I don't know if we can simplify this by using URI schemes